# Как присвоить значения атрибутов объектного типа другому объектному типу с теми же атрибутами?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, типы-данных, oracle19c

Есть два разных обьектных типа с одними и теми же атрибутами. Нужно присвоить значения атрибутов первого типа другому. Они полностью идентичны, за исключением имён схем и типов.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA_A.type_A AS OBJECT(XCOL VARCHAR2(80), YCOL VARCHAR2(80), ZCOL CHAR(2));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA_B.type_B AS OBJECT(XCOL VARCHAR2(80), YCOL VARCHAR2(80), ZCOL CHAR(2));
```

Конечно можно присваивать значения один за другим:

```
SCHEMA_A.type_A.XCOL := SCHEMA_B.type_B.XCOL;
SCHEMA_A.type_A.YCOL := SCHEMA_B.type_B.YCOL;
...
```

Но в действительности у объектов более 80 атрибутов.

Есть ли более элегантный способ достичь того же эффекта?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to assign values of object type attributes to different object type with same attribute properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64414844) от участника [@Boreddo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625281/boreddo)</sub>

Comment: ассооциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64414844

Answer (score 2):

Нет смысла создавать два одинаковых типа в двух разных схемах. Надо оставить только один обьектный тип в одной общей схеме, а затем создавать алиасы в обоих схемах с указанием обьектного типа в общей схеме.

---

Так как невсегда это возможно, например, сушествующие типы уже имеют зависимости в коде или таблицах, то быстрым решением будет - преобразовать с помощью SQL запроса.

Вот воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace type A.objA as object (attr1 varchar2 (8), attr2 int, attr3 date)
/
create or replace type B.objB as object (attr1 varchar2 (8), attr2 int, attr3 date);
/
create or replace type A.objtA as table of A.objA;
/
create or replace type A.objtB as table of B.objB;
/
var rc refcursor 
declare 
    a A.objA;  
    b B.objB := B.objB ('name B', 1, trunc (sysdate));
    function cast (o B.objB) return A.objA is
        t A.objtA;
    begin
        select cast (multiset (select * from A.objtB (b)) 
                 as A.objtA) into t from dual; 
        return t(1);
    end;
begin 
    a := cast (b);
    open :rc for select a a from dual;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
A(ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3)
------------------------------------------------
OBJA('name B', 1, '2020-10-18 00:00:00')
```